# Normal family of functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question and I have no idea how I can solve it. Let $F$ be family of functions $f$ in $A(D)$ where $D=\{x\in\mathbb{C}, \vert x\vert<1\}$ is a unit disc and $A(D)$ denotes the set of analytic functions on $D$.

If:
 $$\begin{cases} 
f(0) &=2i\\ 
\vert f(z)\vert&>1
\end{cases}$$
 for all $z\in D$, then prove that $F$ is a normal family in $A(D)$.

I tried to use montel's but this family of functions is not locally bounded and the same issue with Ascoli-Arzela theorem.

Could you please give me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: Are $A(D)=\text{adh}(D)$ and $D=\{x\in\mathbb{C}, \vert x\vert < 1\}$?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. By A(D)  which is the set of all analytic functions.

Comment: I've corrected my wrong editing :) As an information, the set of analytic functions on some given set $D$ is often denoted $C^{\omega}(D)$, if I'm not mistaken (but it is maybe only in the real case)

Answer (score 4):

We define $$ G:= \bigg\{ \frac{1}{f}\ \ \bigg|\ \ f \in F \bigg\} $$

Easy to see $G \subset A(D)$ is a normal family (since uniformly bounded).

Let $f_n$ be a sequence in $F$.

Define $g_n := \dfrac{1}{f_n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Now, since $G$ is normal, there is a subsequence of $g_n$ (let us say $g_{n_k}$) and a function $g$ such that  $g_{n_k} \to g$ uniformly on $D$.

Check that $f_{n_k} := \frac{1}{g_{n_k}}$ converges uniformly to $f := \frac{1}{g}$ on $D$. (use the fact that $g_n$ are bounded)

Comment: Is there any use of the condition $f(0)=2i$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the family of all reciprocals of functions in $\mathcal{F}$.

Or, use the stronger theorem also called Montel's theorem which states that any family of analytic functions on a region omitting two complex values is normal.

Comment: can you please give some reference for the strong version of the Montel's Theorem

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's here if you have access http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319796?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: A more classic way to prove it (but one which takes a bit more work) is to use the modular function described here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem

Comment: thanks for the interesting article